# How to set different label content for different scales?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-web-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to accomplish conditional labeling based on map scale and attribute in QGIS 1.7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37453/how-to-accomplish-conditional-labeling-based-on-map-scale-and-attribute-in-qgis)

I'd like to show different label content at different map scales. Zoomed in, I use the new labeling (ABC-button) to concatenate different values

```
( "COMPANY_NA"  || '\n' || 'Status Truck: '  ||  "STATUS_TRU"  || '\n' || 'Phone: '  ||   "PHONE_CENT" )
```

Using a CSV-layer, I could combine with the old label function at the layer properties. Somehow, this does not work as I change the CSV layer to a shapefile, the scale properties of the old label function are not kept.

Unfortunately, as I plan to publish the result on the web client, it is not possible for me to use two layers as in [different labels at various scales](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30073/different-labels-at-various-scales)

Using Version 1.8 on Windows XP

Comment: similar http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37453/how-to-accomplish-conditional-labeling-based-on-map-scale-and-attribute-in-qgis

Comment: Solution in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37453/how-to-accomplish-conditional-labeling-based-on-map-scale-and-attribute-in-qgis needs two layers, which is not convenient for displaying over web-client. But I guess there is no solution for a single layer yet... Thanks anyhow!